# Recursion to figure out if a mobile is balanced

Tags: java

A little background on the assignment: "A Mobile is either a rod or a bob. A rod contains two simpler Mobiles. A Bob does not contain any mobiles. When you implement a method on Mobiles, you will need to have a case for bobs and a case for rods. In the rod case you will be coding a recursive case that makes two recursive calls. You will need to figure out how, for example, to define the weight of a rod in terms of the weights of the two Mobiles it supports. In the bob case, you will be coding a base case with no recursion." I cannot change the stubs of the methods, only what is contained inside of them, I tried starting the `isBalanced ()` method, but I don't really know where I'm going. A rod is balanced when the product of its left distance and the weight hanging from its left end equals the product of its right distance and the weight hanging from its right end.  Every rod in the mobile shown above is balanced, so we say that the mobile as a whole is balanced. If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
/**
 * A Mobile is either a Bob or Rod.
 * 
 * A Bob is a Mobile consists of a weight hanging from a vertical wire.
 * 
 * Here's a diagram, where W denotes a weight:
 * 
 * <pre>
 *                             |
 *                             W
 * </pre>
 * 
 * A Rod is a Mobile that consists of a horizontal rod that has one Mobile hanging from its left end and another Mobile
 * hanging from its right end. The rod is hanging from a vertical wire. The distance along the rod from the vertical
 * wire to the left end is called the left length, and the distance from the vertical wire to the right end is called
 * the right length.
 * 
 * Here's a diagram:
 * 
 * <pre>
 *                        _____|__________
 *                        |              |
 *                        L              R
 * </pre>
 * 
 * The left length is 5 and the right length is 10. L and R are the left and right Mobiles, respectively.
 */
public class Mobile
{
/**
 * True if the Mobile is a Bob; false if the Mobile is a Rod.
 */
private boolean isBob;

/**
 * If isBob is true, contains the weight of the Bob.
 */
private int weight;

/**
 * If isBob is false, contains the left length of the Rod.
 */
private int leftLength;

/**
 * If isBob is false, contains the right length of the Rod.
 */
private int rightLength;

/**
 * If isBob is false, contains the left Mobile of the Rod.
 */
private Mobile left;

/**
 * If isBob is false, contains the right Mobile of the Rod.
 */
private Mobile right;

/**
 * Creates a Bob with the given weight.
 */
public Mobile (int weight)
{
    this.isBob = true;
    this.weight = weight;
}

/**
 * Creates a Rod of the given configuration.
 */
public Mobile (int leftLength, int rightLength, Mobile left, Mobile right)
{
    this.isBob = false;
    this.leftLength = leftLength;
    this.left = left;
    this.rightLength = rightLength;
    this.right = right;
}

public boolean isBalanced ()
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by splitting your Mobile class into different sub-classses for Rod and Bob. In the next step you can define different isBalanced() methods for both types. A Bob is always balanced,  for a Rod you have to recursively analyse the left and right Mobile. The recursion automatically stops if it runs into a Bob. 
The total weight of a left or right Mobile that you need to determine if a Mobile is balanced has to be computed recursively as well.